# Why does bash script stop working

Tags: bash, shell, fifo, tail

The script monitors incoming HTTP messages and forwards them to a monitoring application called zabbix, It works fine, however after about 1-2 days it stops working. Heres what I know so far:

- Using `pgrep` i see the script is still running
- the logfile file gets updated properly (first command of script)
- The FIFO pipe seems to be working

The problem must be somewhere in WHILE loop or tail command.
Im new at scripting so maybe someone can spot the problem right away?

```
#!/bin/bash
tcpflow -p -c -i enp2s0 port 80 | grep --line-buffered -oE 'boo.php.* HTTP/1.[01]' >> /usr/local/bin/logfile &

pipe=/tmp/fifopipe

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
        mkfifo  $pipe
fi

tail -n0 -F /usr/local/bin/logfile > /tmp/fifopipe &

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then

        unset sn

        for ((c=1; c<=3; c++)) # c is no of max parameters x 2 + 1
        do
                URL="$(echo $line | awk -F'[ =&?]' '{print $'$c'}')"

                if [[ "$URL" == 'sn' ]]; then
                ((c++))
                sn="$(echo $line | awk -F'[ =&?]' '{print $'$c'}')"
                fi

        done

        if [[ "$sn"  ]]; then
                        hosttype="US2G_"
                        host=$hosttype$sn
                        zabbix_sender -z nuc -s $host -k serial -o $sn -vv
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to variable $host?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I simplified the script a little just to post here, I do assign it. Fixed the post

Comment: What changed from when things worked to when things didn't? Was someone making changes to this script around that time? If so, what does your VCS show? Does an older version of the script still work? Or if the script didn't change in that time, what makes you think changing the script will fix the problem? (If you run the `zabbix_sender` command manually, what happens?)

Comment: Nothing was changed. The script runs smooth, HTTP messages get sent to zabbix, and after 1-2 days without even logging in to the server, it stops working. 'zabbix_sender' works ok manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inputting from the fifo incorrectly.  By writing:

```
while true; do read line < $pipe ....; done
```

you are closing and reopening the fifo on each iteration of the loop.  The first time you close it, the producer to the pipe (the tail -f) gets a SIGPIPE and dies.  Change the structure to:

```
while true; do read line; ...; done < $pipe
```

Note that every process inside the loop now has the potential to inadvertently read from the pipe, so you'll probably want to explicitly close stdin for each.

Comment: I rearranged the loop like you described. I quess I can see in few days if that fixed the issue. But how do you close stdin for each process?

Comment: You can also avoid the problem of other processes reading from the pipe by sending it over fd #3 instead of stdin (aka fd #0): `while true; do read line <&3; ...; done 3< $pipe`

Comment: @tarmogr To close, you can do `<&-`.  eg.  `zabbix_sender <&- args`

Comment: Seems to be working fine now, thank you all for input!